# Understanding connection between hypothetical scenarios and validity.

Tags: logic

In P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (Chapter 2), appear several examples concerning validity of arguments:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{Either Mei is a mathematician or a botanist.}\\
&\text{Mei isn’t a botanist.}\\
&\therefore \text{Mei is an acrobat.}
\end{align}
$$

> This argument is clearly not valid, since we can imagine a mathematician named Mei who is not an acrobat.

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{London is in England.}\\
&\text{Beijing is in China}\\
&\therefore \text{Paris is in France}
\end{align}
$$

> The premises and conclusion of this argument are, as a matter of fact, all true, but the argument is invalid. If Paris were to declare independence from the rest of France, then the conclusion would no longer be true, even though both of the premises would remain true.

My questions are:

- In the explanation of the first argument, what's the meaning of "we can imagine a mathematician named Mei who is not an acrobat ?". How is this hypothetical scenario constructed?
- In the explanation of the second argument, what's the meaning of "If Paris were to declare independence from the rest of France, then the conclusion would no longer be true"? Is it connected with the fact that premises and conclusions are not "tied", i.e. the argument has not a valid logic form and hence it allows for a possibility where premises are true and conclusion false?

Comment: Not a direct answer but a suggestion. In general, if one logic text leaves you a bit puzzled about some fundamental points, *look at another*.  In particular, the Magnus text has the virtue of great brevity, but it has the shortcomings of great brevity: you will find more expansive explanations of this sort of thing if you look at early chapters of other books -- there will be literally dozens to choose from.

Comment: "hypotetical scenario" can be misleading: *valid* means "True in every interpretation". The above example can be used to show that the corresponding *argument form* is **not** valid. Consider the argument form: $M(m) \lor B(m), \lnot B(m), \text { therefore } A(m)$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @PeterSmith. I just started reading Paul Teller's book by your recommendation in _Teach Yourself Logic_ and it is really valuable !

Comment: Thank you, @MauroALLEGRANZA. "True in every interpretation", using your simbolization, would mean that: for any name _m_ that belongs to the domain, $((M(m) \lor B(m)) \land \lnot B(m)) \to A(m)$ is true ?

Comment: Not only: also for every interpretation of predicate symbols M, B and A.